# Explanation for function initialization

Tags: javascript

We can init function in such way

```
0[c="constructor"][c]`q=_=>1`()
q(); //1
```

As I take in it is the same as

```
Function`q=_=>1`()
```

But I never saw such syntax.

Why and how does it work?

Comment: `0[c="constructor"][c]` is a short way of writing `(0).constructor.constructor`. Take a look at the values of `(0).constructor` and `(0).constructor.constructor` in your console.

Comment: There's more to this than just [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates). You also need to know what calling `Function` without `new` does and how arrays stringify.

Comment: @melpomene `Function` without `new` works just like `Function` with `new`. And what does this have to do with arrays?

Comment: @Bergi The code is equivalent to `Function(['q=_=>1'])()`. It passes an array to `Function`.

Comment: @melpomene Oops, how could I forget that. But the duplicate seems to explain this well